# How to create an Interface Builder plugin in XCode5+?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode5

I need make an **Object Library**, an Interface Builder plugin like **`Mapkit`** so that user can drag my Custom Object and add to `UIView`.

[image]

As property, i want to show and configure it with my basic properties.

Any idea how to do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Xcode 4.0, Apple has removed support for using custom Interface Builder palettes provided by IBPlugins in the Interface Builder editor. Xibs/Nibs that use such plugins will still compile but they cannot be edited. You'll need to install Xcode 3 (in a separate folder so as not to overwrite 4) and use it to edit xibs with custom palettes.

This is all in Xcode 4's release notes. Stay tuned to prerelease release notes for more updates on this matter.

***Update for Xcode 6***

Plugins are no longer necessary. See @IBDesignable and @IBInspectable. :-)

Comment: A friend of mine wrote an article about how he successfully created an interface builder plugin for Xcode 4: http://www.inline-studios.com/developer/articles/1-Xcode_4_Interface_Builder_Plugins/

Comment: @JustinMeiners How about posting that as an answer? :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an Interface Builder plugin for that; the static library has nothing Interface Builder knows how to work with.

Comment: Take a look at Apple's website for info. Note that IB plugin support was dropped for Xcode 4--you cannot do what you want to do unless you're using Xcode 3 or earlier.

Comment: Whoops. Didn't catch that in your comment. Apologies.

Comment: A question has to be edited first after a certain period of time. Went ahead and edited it. +1 for your troubles.