# Create Interface Builder palette for exposeBinding

Tags: swift, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings, nsslider

I followed my understanding of how to expose a property of an NSSlider subclass  in Interface Builder but it is not showing up.   I want to be able to bind the property in a viewcontroller through Interface Builder to track the movement of the slider better.

Here's the subclass

```
@objc class GJSlider: NSSlider {

   @objc dynamic var sliderMouseEnd: Bool = false

    override var exposedBindings: [NSBindingName] {
        get {
            var temp = super.exposedBindings
            temp.append(NSBindingName(rawValue: "sliderMouseEnd"))

            return temp
        }
    }

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        GJSlider.exposeBinding(NSBindingName(rawValue: "sliderMouseEnd"))
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }


    override class func valueClassForBinding(_ binding: NSBindingName) -> AnyClass? {
        if binding == NSBindingName(rawValue: "sliderMouseEnd") {
            return Optional<Bool>.self as! AnyClass
        } else {
            return super.valueClassForBinding(binding)
        }
    }
}
```

After reviewing the documentation more, the NSKeyValueBindingCreation says:

NSView subclasses can expose additional key-value-coding/key-value-observing compliant properties as bindings by calling the class method exposeBinding(_:) for each of the properties. This is typically done in the class’s initialize method. By exposing the bindings that an object supports and creating an **Interface Builder palette**, you can make instances of your own classes bindable in Interface Builder.

So I guess the important point is how do I create an "Interface Builder palette"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [+exposeBinding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058282/exposebinding-not-working)

Comment: Thanks.  I guess these methods should be deprecated then if there is no way to use them with modern Xcode.  Or at least better documented.

Comment: I modified the question to clarify the issue is creating an Interface Builder palette.

Comment: See [How to create an Interface Builder plugin in XCode5+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568817/how-to-create-an-interface-builder-plugin-in-xcode5/6610658#6610658)